# react-router v4: Determine if route has been matched from outside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a component which **always** needs to be rendered, but should only be visible if no routes have been matched (`<Iframe isVisible={ifNoRoutesMatched} />`).

So far I didn't find a nice way to check if that is the case. I went down this horrendous route of setting a variable to state with component wrappers but there must be a better way!? Also this needs `withRouter` and `PureComponent` otherwise the `catchAllWrapper` causes an infinite render loop:

```
class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    routeMatched: false,
  }

  catchAllWrapper = () => {
    this.setState({ routeMatched: false });
    return null;
  }

  routeWrapper = (RouteComponent) => {
    const RouteWrapper = (props) => {
      this.setState({ routeMatched: true });
      return <RouteComponent {...props} />;
    };

    return RouteWrapper;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/chat" component={this.routeWrapper(Chat)} />
          ...more routes...
          <Route component={this.catchAllWrapper} />
        </Switch>
        <Iframe isVisible={!this.state.routeMatched} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

I would rather have a manual array of route strings compare against than add this complexity!

`this.props.match` only has info on the route it matched INSIDE the matching component so it's pretty useless.

Is there are better way to do this?

**Use case:** it is an iframe which has a legacy app loaded on some routes, so it should not be destroyed and re-rendered between routes

Comment: What is your use case that requires the component always be rendered but only visible when no other routes are matched? I'm asking so that I can formulate an accurate response.

Comment: @KyleRichardson added use case at the bottom, it's an iframe with a legacy app that needs to maintain state between routes

Comment: I believe https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match/null-matches is what you're looking for. So you use a route with the `children` prop and it ill always be rendered. Inside that route you have access to the match and can set it visible when the value is null.

Comment: What about removing the `routeWrapper` and changing the default value of the state to `routeMatched: true` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a lightweight dummy component for the router to mount and unmount freely, then bind callback methods from your current class to its lifecycle events?

```
class Dummy extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.didMount();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.willUnmount();
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    showIframe: false,
  }

  cbDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ showIframe: true });
  }

  cbWillUnmount = () => {
    this.setState({ showIframe: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/chat" component={Chat} />
          {/* more routes */}
          <Route render={() => <Dummy didMount={this.cbDidMount} willUnmount={this.cbWillUnmount} />} />
        </Switch>
        <Iframe isVisible={this.state.showIframe} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Neat idea and it works with some small mods (turns out `component` prop isn't passed custom props so need to use `render` with a callback)! Seems like the best solution so far will just keep it open a bit longer thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Wrote the original answer on my phone, so I figured it wouldn't be perfect

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you. Use a [Route](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string) that does not have a `path` property (these always render) and you can check for a [null match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match/null-matches) inside the component.

Here is a working [CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4355n224q7)

Open the console on the bottom to see that it is always rendered.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but match always comes through as `{path: "/", url: "/", params: {}, isExact: false}` regardless of what route it's on. I found that it was only correct in the component that actually matched.

Comment: @Dominic I made a working example in a codesandbox for you.

Comment: @Dominic I added a redirect scenario and multiple testing routes to illustrate that it does work. Play with it.

Comment: ah I see what your doing outside the switch and with the redirect. That's a neat solution but unfortunately I want to keep the unmatched path on the URL not redirect it, as this URL is passed into the iframe for it's own routing

Comment: @Dominic that's easy to do with a redirect to object. `<Redirect from='*' to={{path: '/', state: {referrer: props.match.path}}} />` You can then access that in your outer component via `props.location.state.refferer` and pass that value into the iframe. I believe this is the most idiomatic method.

Answer (score 0):

To show a component when no route match you can use the below code:

```
               <Switch>                  
                {this.props.notLoggedIn === true
                  ? <Route path='/' component={LandingPage}/>                                          
                  : <Dashboard />                    
                }
                <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
              </Switch>
```

In the above case I show the landing page as the default route and in case the user is logged in the dashboard is shown (contains more route like your chat one).

If no route is matched the `PageNotFound` component is shown.

For a working example feel free to take a look at : https://github.com/osamamaruf/reactnd-project-would-you-rather/blob/master/src/components/App.js
and the repo link is : https://github.com/osamamaruf/reactnd-project-would-you-rather

Comment: Thanks but this component ALWAYS needs to be rendered, just not visible if no routes match. Switch only renders one route.

Comment: @Dominic You mean IS visible when no routes match? `but should only be visible if no routes have been matched`

Comment: Yep sorry, always rendered but only visible if no routes match, thanks @DarrenSweeney